# Display multiple images stored in database from servlet

Tags: servlets

I am making a webpage using jsp and servlets. I am facing a problem when trying to display several images in jsp page. It take toooo long to display them and it as only a dozen images.

THe code follows.

```
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)) {                                        
                ps = con.prepareStatement("select foto from utilizadores where id = ?");
                ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")));
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()){



                    imgBytes = rs.getBytes("foto");
                    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
                    response.setContentLength(imgBytes.length);
                    response.getOutputStream().write(imgBytes);

                    response.getOutputStream().flush();
                    response.getOutputStream().close();

                }
```

Them i am normally displaying the image in the jsp file.

```
<img alt="foto de perfil" src="/uShare/socialImgServlet?id=<%=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("idUtilizador"))%>">
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is the question?

Comment: As i said. It is taking too long to display them. I would love to read some tips to improve performance

Comment: How much images are return by SQL request (tens, hundreds, ...) and what is approximately size of one image?

Comment: At this point i have about 10 images and each image about 2Mb.

Comment: Thanks to you i found a solution. I didnt reallized the images were so big. So i added compression to them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just hadded compression to the image and that´s it. It is faster.

But if i would not want to do that, i found that it´s slower to have the image saved has a blob rather tan the absolute path to it.